# spring-boot-maven-plugin include other projects from workspace

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a spring STS project which depends on two other projects in the same workspace. I have included them in my pom.xml but when I build jar they are excluded from the generated jar.Could you please let me know how to include these two dependent projects in the build.

I have below entries in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.acord.standards.life</groupId>
            <artifactId>txlife</artifactId>
            <version>2.37.00</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxx.service.query</groupId>
            <artifactId>queryutil</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.acord.standards.life</groupId>
            <artifactId>txlife</artifactId>
            <version>2.37.00</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxx.service.query</groupId>
            <artifactId>queryutil</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <attach>true</attach>
                <!-- <includes>
                    <include>
                        <groupId>org.acord.standards.life</groupId>
                        <artifactId>txlife</artifactId>
                        <version>2.37.00</version>
                        <classifier>2.37.00</classifier>
                    </include>
                    <include>
                        <groupId>com.xxx.service.query</groupId>
                        <artifactId>queryutil</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                        <classifier>1.0</classifier>
                    </include>
                </includes> -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem following [this documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/) from Spring.io.

An alternative approach is you run Maven Install for each dependency project and, after it, set them in your pom.xml (in your main project). For example, I have a main spring project called **Alna Rest** that depends of others particular spring projects how **Alna Data** and **Alna Service**, then, in my Alna Rest project my pom.xml has this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alna.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>alna-data</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alna.service</groupId>
        <artifactId>alna-service</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

After it I can run Maven Install in my Alna Rest project that the Spring Boot Maven Plugin build an executable jar with all projects dependencies.

Well, this works for me. But I don't know if it is the better approach for build a project that requires many othes spring boot projects. Then I recommend you search more about this.